# Speed up sql INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN combination statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking to improve the performance of the following sql statment as this takes over 7 seconds to search 850,000 records.

```
select c.productTitle
     , c.catalogue_id
     , s1.catalogue_id
     , s1.cpc 
  FROM store s1 
  JOIN catalogue c 
    ON s1.catalogue_id = c.catalogue_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN store s2 
    ON (s1.catalogue_id = s2.catalogue_id AND s1.cpc < s2.cpc)
 WHERE s2.cpc IS NULL 
  AND c.productTitle LIKE '%user-query-here%'
GROUP 
   BY c1.catalogue_id
```

I have a catalogue table with 850,000 products (non duplicates) and a store table that contains the sale price of each product, the store table can have duplicates as more then one seller can sell the same product.

Catalogue table

```
| catalogue_id | productTitle      | barcode |
| 1            | washing machine   | abc     |
| 2            | dish washer       | def     |
| 3            | toaster           | ghi     |
| 4            | kettle            | jkl     |
| 5            | mobile phone 8gb  | mno     |
```

Store table

```
| product_id | catalogue_id      | cpc     |
| 1001       | 1                 | 0.01     |
| 2001       | 1                 | 0.02     |
| 3001       | 2                 | 0.05     |
| 4001       | 3                 | 0.01     |
| 5001       | 1                 | 0.05     |
```

expected results...

(grouped washing machine by catalogue_id and only display the product by highest cost per click (cpc) )

```
washing machine | 5001 | 0.05 
dish washer     | 3001 | 0.05
toaster         | 4001 | 0.01
```

Regards

Comment: can you add more information about the index or same query with explain result to it !!!

Comment: AND s1.cpc < s2.cpc)
WHERE s2.cpc IS NULL - seems a bit odd and I don't like group bys wihout aggregate functions -see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Yep, this query doesn't make a lot of sense right now, See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), and note that as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: sorry, just updated my post with more information

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the majority of time is spent on `AND c.productTitle LIKE '%user-query-here%'`.

The bad news is that you can't make an ordinary index on this condition, so the database has to go through all the records and perform substring matching for every record.

If you cannot think of any other way of doing it (i.e. replacing `LIKE` with `=`), then full-text search is what you need. The good news is that MySQL has a [built-in FTS support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you was right. I changed from like to Match() Against() in my statment, this has speeded up the sql. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well you should redefine your SQL. The first JOIN is probably an INNER JOIN please use it to make clear intention. Get the queries nested.

```
select c.productTitle
     , c.catalogue_id
     , s1.catalogue_id
     , s1.cpc 
  FROM store s1 
  JOIN catalogue c 
    ON s1.catalogue_id = c.catalogue_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN store s2 
    ON (s1.catalogue_id = s2.catalogue_id AND s1.cpc < s2.cpc)
 WHERE s2.cpc IS NULL
```

into one query and the rest outside, but also consider to avoid IS NULL statement and have for that an empty code.

One more question is the ordering of the tables in the query. Take the smallest tables first or tables that give you the smallest product from the join and than do the rest.

The next question is what kind of indices on the tables you have. If the querie takes 7s than you should experiment around what will function best.

At one more problem is how busy is your I/O unit if that is not the problem than the redesign should work.

Comment: I did originally post it as an INNER JOIN but someone edited my post and changed it to JOIN.

Comment: :) inner is used to be expressive, at least I do it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at possible causes, turns out it was
`Innodb buffer pool size` was too low.

I changed to pool size and changed the `like` to `MATCH() AGAINST()` with redefined  indexes within the table.

Thanks for your responses.